# visiting http://localhost/ after running ./vendor/bin/sail up shows the Apache2 Ubuntu Default Page instead of the laravel app

Tags: laravel, docker-compose, laravel-sail

I'm using Linux and I already have docker compose installed.

After creating an application with `curl -s https://laravel.build/example-app | bash`,
running `./vendor/bin/sail up` and visiting `http://localhost/` in the browser I see Apache2 Ubuntu Default Page instead of the new laravel app. How can I fix the issue?

Below is part of the output when I run `./vendor/bin/sail up`

```
[+] Building 0.0s (0/0)                                                                                                                                                                                      
[+] Running 4/0
 ✔ Container example-app-meilisearch-1  Created                                                                                                                                                         0.0s 
 ✔ Container example-app-redis-1        Created                                                                                                                                                         0.0s 
 ✔ Container example-app-mailpit-1      Created                                                                                                                                                         0.0s 
 ✔ Container example-app-selenium-1     Created                                                                                                                                                         0.0s 
Attaching to example-app-laravel.test-1, example-app-mailpit-1, example-app-meilisearch-1, example-app-mysql-1, example-app-redis-1, example-app-selenium-1
```